# Bordered elements with non-bordered pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

A problem I encounter frequently is when I have a breadcrumb list like

```
<ul class="horizontal-list">
    <li><a href="/home.html">Here's a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="/home/subpage.html">Here's another link</a></li>
    <li>Here's the final link</li>
</ul>
```

```css
ul.horizontal-list > li { display: inline; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
ul.horizontal-list > li + li:before { content: ">"; padding: 0 3px;}
ul.horizontal-list > li > a { text-decoration: none;}
```

and I want the pseudo-elements to **not** have the border, or some other property, that their elements have. Adding `border-bottom: 0;` to `ul.horizontal-list > li + li:before` does not achieve my end. Why doesn't it?

Here's a fiddle of the scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/oboy1a4r/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oboy1a4r/1/ Is that what you try to achieve?

Comment: @gearsdigital I want a border on the last list element as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pseudo-elements indeed don't have any borders, which means setting `border-bottom: 0` does nothing; however, as they are [part of the originating `li` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content), they are rendered within the `li` element boxes and so the `li` borders extend to the pseudo-elements.

A simple solution to this problem is to apply the border to the `a` child elements instead of the `li` elements. This way the pseudo-elements exist separately from the bordered boxes.

If you need the last item to have a border as well, you could wrap its text in a `span` element and apply the border to `li > a, li > span`:

```
<ul class="horizontal-list">
    <li><a href="/home.html">Here's a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="/home/subpage.html">Here's another link</a></li>
    <li><span>Here's the final link</span></li>
</ul>
```

... but if you prefer to do this in pure CSS without the use of extraneous markup, you will need to

1. change the `:before` pseudo-elements to `:after` pseudo-elements,
2. apply the pseudo-elements to all but the last `li` (`li:not(:last-child)`) instead of all but the first (`li + li`), and
3. apply the border to the `a` elements as well as the last `li`.

Keep in mind that the use of `:last-child` will cost you IE8 compatibility; if that is a priority then you will have to make do with using a `span` element with `li + li:before` as mentioned above.

```css
ul.horizontal-list > li:not(:last-child):after {
    content: ">";
    padding: 0 3px;
}

ul.horizontal-list > li > a, ul.horizontal-list > li:last-child {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/oboy1a4r/2)

On a final note, since all of the boxes (including the pseudo-elements) are inline, using whitespace instead of padding will [provide consistent spacing between the pseudo-elements and the rest of the text](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/oboy1a4r/3):

```css
ul.horizontal-list > li:not(:last-child):after {
    content: " > ";
}
```

(Technically, you don't need the trailing space because the newline after each `</li>` end tag fulfills the role of whitespace for this purpose, but you can include it for the sake of consistency and it will [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model) normally.)

Comment: 1+ for linking to the relevant documentation. I wasn't sure if it would be correct to state that pseudo elements *are* children elements since they technically don't exist in the DOM.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: They do not exist in the DOM (called the document tree in CSS), however the boxes rendered in the layout (the formatting structure) are indeed children of the actual elements' boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* add the `border-bottom` to the child `a` elements instead:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/oLnzggkx/)

```
ul.horizontal-list > li > a { border-bottom: 1px solid #000; }
```

The reason `border-bottom: 0` didn't work on the pseudo element was because the border *wasn't* on the pseudo element. It's worth pointing out that the `:before` pseudo element acts as a child element of the `li` element. Thus, a border will encompass the entire element, including the pseudo element since it is essentially *in* the parent element with the border.